# Contrast thread crashes with a process crash

Tags: multithreading, process, crash

I'm having trouble on distinguishing how thread crashes differ from a process crash.
 Is there even any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  A thread can exit while the process remains active.  For example, a thread can exit either normally or by throwing an exception out of its stack, and it stops execution, but other threads in the process will continue to execute normally, and the process heap space will continue to be allocated.  If the process crashes - or if it exits normally - all threads not already terminated will terminate and all memory allocated by the process will be released.